# How to replicate the partition key word in LINQ

Tags: sql, linq, model-view-controller

I am new to MVC and I've been thrown in at the deep end so apologies for what is probably an easy question.
I'm trying to convert some SQL into its equivalent code in LINQ

```
with myresults as(
 select [useridfrom], [mid], [subject], [msgText], [created], 
 ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY mid ORDER BY created DESC) AS rNumber
 from msg where useridto = @useridto
) 
select * from myresults where rnumber = 1
```

This is what I have done so far but I can't figure out how to do the partition bit

```
var query = from p in db.msgs
join mb in db.members on p.userIDFrom equals mb.userID
where p.userIDTo == userID
orderby p.created descending
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to group by `mid` then within the group sort and select the first. The resulting SQL may well be less efficient than the CTE (ie. why not use the currently SQL wrapper in a stored proc and call that from your application?).

Something like (this assumes EF and LINQ to Entities):

```
var res = await (from m in myContent.Messages
                 group m by m.mid into grp
                 let maxInGrp = (from g in grp
                                 order by g.created descending
                                 select g).FirstOrDefault()                     
                 select maxInGrp
                ).ToListAsync();
```